# color coding in infopath sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-data-connections

how can i use color coding formula when using infopath. i have something called as project health and it has three choices 
1. on track
2. major issues
3. minor issues
when we select on track i want green circle
when we select major issues i want red diamond
when we select minor issues i want yellow triangle. 
how can i do that using infopath. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Mohammed

Comment: Are you talking about on the form or in the Sharepoint list view?

Comment: in the form we will select on track or major issues and on the list it must display the color coding.

Comment: what i did earlier was i created a list column called color status and selected calculated formula as =IF(OR(Status="On Track")," Green",IF(OR(Status="Major Setbacks"),"Red",IF(OR(Status="Minor Setbacks"),"Orange")))  and then i created one more column name project progress to plan and gave calculated formula as ="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&[Color Status]&";'>•</DIV>"                 But since i have infopath in this SP site this is not working

Answer (score 0):

In InfoPath you can add three sections to your form. In each section upload an image, circle, diamond, triangle. For each section use a formatting rule that looks at the status field.

For the section with the green symbol, hide the section if the status is no equal to "on track". For the other sections use individual rules along the same lines.

The list view in SharePoint can show the words of your calculated column (green, red, orange), and you can use SharePoint Designer to set a conditional format with the color you want to see on the row.

Comment: Do you know the formula to change for stop light to indicator. Currently I have like this  ="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&[Color Status]&";'>•</DIV>"      I want to change to indicator, like red color in rectangle, orange in triangle and green in round

Comment: I don't understand where you are applying that HTML. Can you explain? Which tool? Post a screenshot.

Comment: I tried using infopath I felt complicated so what I did was I created  a list column called color status and tried to use html for that now the color coding works but all I get is red dot yellow dot and green dot instead I need red triangle green dot and yellow rectangle since I have some people who are color blindness and they can't see dot difference

Comment: Your question is about how to do this with InfoPath. A calculated column is a completely different topic.